# Compressing Image in C#

Tags: c#, image, compression, filesize

How can I compress an image to be lower than 1kb? Is it possible?

Here Is the code that I have managed to create using some references online.

It reduces the image file size up to 1.2 kb but the image quality is greatly reduced

> Function For Compressing The Image

```
    private void SaveAndCompressImage()
    {
            if (OriginalImage == null) return;
            long compression = long.Parse(20);
            string file_name = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + 
     "filename.jpg";
            OriginalImage = new Bitmap(OriginalImage, new Size(100, 100));
            SaveJpg(OriginalImage, file_name, compression);

            // Display the result without locking the file.
            UserPic.Image = LoadBitmapUnlocked(file_name);
            Image PictureBoxPic = UserPic.Image;
            Image pic = new Bitmap(PictureBoxPic, new Size(100, 100));
            // Used For applying grayscale reduces image file size
            Image gray_scale_image = ToolStripRenderer.CreateDisabledImage(pic);

            Image output = gray_scale_image;  

            output.Save( file, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            // Used to Convert Image to Base64
            ConvertImageToBase64 = Functions.CreateBase64Image(file);
}
```

> Used For Saving the Image with The Compression Level

```
// Save the file with a specific compression level.
private void SaveJpg(Image image, string file_name, long compression)
{
    try
    {
        EncoderParameters encoder_params = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoder_params.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, compression);

        ImageCodecInfo image_codec_info = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
        File.Delete(file_name);
        image.Save(file_name, image_codec_info, encoder_params);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

> Load a bitmap without locking it.

```
private Bitmap LoadBitmapUnlocked(string file_name)
{
    using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(file_name))
    {
        return new Bitmap(bm);
    }
}
```

> Return an ImageCodecInfo object for this mime type

```
private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mime_type)
{
    ImageCodecInfo[] encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
    for (int i = 0; i <= encoders.Length; i++)
    {
        if (encoders[i].MimeType == mime_type) return encoders[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You need to use trial and error, lowering the quality until the result in small enough.

Comment: Sorry if my reply is out of the topic of my question but do you think it is viable to pass a base64 string of an image into a qr code?

Comment: This I do not know.

Comment: According to wikipedia, QR codes used in binary mode can store almost 3k.